# fastest way for convert a block of data in a column to different columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I have bunch of data in a column that every 500 rows contain a block of data. I want to move each 500rows to a new column and put them next of each other as shown image, my preference solution is using some excel solution(trick) instead of coding. kindly if you know any solution please help me otherwise suggest me your VBA solution.
Tq

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link for the solution.

[Here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/681-excel-change-columns-to-rows.html)

Convert a single column to a range of data from column to column:

The above formula can help you to transpose the single column to range from row to row, if you need to transpose column to range from column to column, the follwoing formula also can do you a favor.

1. In a blank cell C1, please enter this formula:=INDEX($A$1:$A$20,ROW(C1)+(5*(COLUMNS($C$1:C$1)-1))), and then drag the fill handle from C1 to C5

Note: A1:A20 is the column data that you want to convert, 5* stands for the number of cells that you want to have in each column.

2. Then drag the fill handle across C column to F column, and the data in single column has been transposed to a range from column to column.